# Apply a function to a list of object and corresponding strings

Tags: r

I have a list of objects `object_list` a list of strings `string_list` and a `function` that needs an object and a string.

I want to apply my function to every object and pass a different string from a list each time. The `string_list` and `object_list` have the same length and order.

How do I do this?

I tried:

```
myfuntion <- function(object,filename) {
}

input <- list(a,b,c)

filename_list <- c("a","b","c")

lapply(input, myfunction, filename=filename_list)
```

But that does not work

Comment: Please, provide a minimal reproducible example:  [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I added a longer example, I hope this is more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following, using `mapply`:

```r
myfuntion <- function(object,filename) {
  paste(object, filename)
}

input <- list("a","b","c")

filename_list <- c("a","b","c")

mapply(myfuntion, input, filename_list)

#> [1] "a a" "b b" "c c"
```